# Unbounded sequence that does not diverge to $+ \infty$ or to $- \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to find an example of sequences such that

$$a_n \to + \infty \quad \text{and} \quad b_n \to 0$$

$$a_n b_n \text{  is unbounded but does not diverge to }+ \infty \text{ or} - \infty$$

Is that even possible? I can only think of sequences that are bounded but not convergent; $(-1)^n$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HINT: Make $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ diverge to $+\infty$ rapidly and $\langle b_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converge to $0$ slowly **and with oscillating sign**.

Comment: @Jack: Glad it helped!

Comment: @Jack: I was thinking of $n^2$ and $\frac{(-1)^n}n$ for $n\ge 1$, just because it’s really simple.

Answer (score 5):

If we start from good $a_n\cdot b_n$, say $a_n\cdot b_n=n(-1)^n$, the rest is simple, e.g. $a_n=n^2$, $b_n=\frac1n(-1)^n$.